# Polymer 1.0 - card layout

Tags: polymer-1.0

Since Polymer 0.5 included card layout, I missed it very much in Polymer 1.0. I have tried a lot of things and googled a whole day to find a good solution. For those, having same trouble, I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Polymer element catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) there is an element called [paper-material](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-material). This looks to be want you want to use.

Comment: Or you could use `paper-card` in Polymer 1.0 - https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-card

Comment: Thanks for adding that. The `paper-card` element was ported to 1.0 just over 3 weeks ago so wasn't available when I answered.